# Php : create a class with eval

Tags: php, eval, prestashop

I am watching the code of Prestashop, and I see the following :

```
eval(($class_infos->isAbstract() ? 'abstract ' : '').'class '.$classname.' extends '.$classname.'Core {}');
```

They use this in order to override the core class, in the autoload method (complete file is  [PrestaShop / classes / Autoload.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/development/classes/Autoload.php#L55)) I am just wondering if its a good thing to create dynamic class like this:

- Will this class be cached by APC or an op code optimizer?
- What about performance?

Comment: The more important question here is "why do this in the first place?". I don't know Presta, but on the surface this looks... just bad.

Comment: Prestashop is a very famous french ecommerce solution with Php and mysql. But the code is very bad, there is no framework behind and the result is very very slow :/ But very famous (french are good to put all the money in advertising ^^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am just wondering if its a good thing to create dynamic class like this:

No.

> Will this class be cached by APC or an op code optimizer?

No.

> What about performance?

No!

<sup>(CW-ified. Feel free to flesh out answer.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I found eval is very horrible as well ^^ No autocompletion in IDE etc... I am going to ask them directly why they wrote this.

Comment: Actually, it performs better than include files ! Cannot believe it at all but its true, well done Prestashop.